# SVG path - maximum number of control points before performance is affected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I am planning to create a complex line drawing using a single SVG path and then animate the path stroke via javascript to create a "self-drawing" animation.

Is there a certain number of path control points after which browser performance starts being seriously affected? If so, would breaking the single path into multiple shorter paths (but totaling the same number of points in the end) improve performance? I can test it out on my laptop and PC, but I think they are generally higher tiered than the average user's machine, so I'd prefer to err on the side of caution. Thanks!

edit: I'm obviously not looking for an exact number, but even a range of "tens", "hundreds" or "thousands" of nodes would be useful to know.

edit 2: To clarify, I would only animate the stroke dasharray. The control points and the path itself would not be animated.

Comment: no need for sarcasm :) I'm obviously not looking for an exact number, but even a range of "tens", "hundreds" or "thousands" of nodes would be useful to know. In my particular case, I would probably not exceed several hundred control points, but maybe others who will see this questions would.

Comment: It will still depend completely on which device would have to run the code, from which implementation, while doing what-else at the same moment etc. You can't have an answer to this question. Ps: sorry for sarcasm, removed

Comment: Just to clear it up: are you planning to animate the stroke-dasharray, or will you be moving the control points themselves?

Comment: Well, I'm not necessarily looking for a definitive answer, I updated my question to narrow it down to orders of magnitude. There's no control over how many tab windows the user already has opened :D That said, if the difference between 100 control points and several hundred is negligible, it would be great to know

Comment: @ccprog I would only animate the stroke. The control points as well as the whole path itself will be static. I will update the question too.